# Java generics: bound class extend class OR 2 interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I've done some reading on defining a bounded type parameters like

```
abstract class AbstractClass < T extends ClassA >

abstract class AbstractClass < T extends InterfaceSeq & InterfaceClone >
```

My problem is the following. My `AbstractClass` needs to have access to a data object's (T) following methods:

```
getSeq() - gets sequence number of data object

_clone() - additional cloning logic of the data object
```

Both these methods are present under `ClassA`. The problem is, `ClassA` was introduced two years ago.

There are old data classes that implement `InterfaceSeq` (has `getSeq()`) and `InterfaceClone` (has `_clone()`):

```
 DataClassA extends ClassA

 DataClassB implements InterfaceSeq, InterfaceClone
```

Both `DataClassA` & `DataClassB` have the 2 methods I need, but I'm having a hard time defining that logic in my `AbstractClass`.

Right now I have:

```
AbstractClass < T extends ClassA >
```

I need something like

```
AbstractClass < T extends ClassA or (InterfaceSeq & InterfaceClone) >
```

Migrating the old classes to use `ClassA` is too complex. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: This may be outlandish, but there's also the possibility of not using bounded types, and just doing `instanceof` checks.

Answer (score 3):

A few options

1. Just make `ClassA` implement both `InterfaceSeq` and `InterfaceClone` and then you can use the

   ```
   abstract class AbstractClass < T extends InterfaceSeq & InterfaceClone >
   ```

   form.
2. Wrap all `ClassA` usage in an adaptor

   ```
   public class ClassAAdaptor<T extends ClassA> implements InterfaceSeq, InterfaceClone {
       private final T value;
       ClassAAdaptor(T value) {
          this.value = value;
       }
       @Override public Seq _getSeq() { return value.getSeq(); }
       @Override public ClassAAdaptor<T> clone() { return new ClassAAdaptor(value.clone()); }
   }
   ```
3. Make two different `AbstractClass`es one for each case, each implementint an interface.

   ```
   interface IAbstractClass { ... }
   class AbstractClassForInterface< T extends InterfaceSeq & InterfaceClone > implements IAbstractClass { ... }
   class AbstractClassForClassA< T extends ClassA > implements IAbstractClass { ... }
   ```

Comment: ClassA is a framework component and would go through an approval process if any changes are to be made there. This is possible, but something I'll do as last resort.

Comment: I've aded a few more options for cases where the first option is "tricky"

Comment: An issue with the third solution is that these are abstract classes, which means they must be extended to be used. Which class would you extend? Because you can't extend both.

Comment: I'm _assuming_ the actual version to be used would be determined by the constructor parameters. If that's not the case, and the generic is really only on the function calls then you'd need to use something closer to case 2. We don't really have enough info about how the `AbstractClass` is getting used and created to determine which is best.

Comment: AbstractClass is used as a caching class for data classes. Data classes which extend (the new) ClassA, are migrated easily, but we're having difficulty migrating the older data classes. 

#3 seems easiest to implement but that would mean I'd have duplicate code for AbstractClassForInterface and AbstractClassForClassA right?

Comment: You can avoid duplication of code in case 3  by switching the `IAbstractClass` from an interface to an abstract class and moving the duplicated functionality into it - all that need be in the derived classes is the glue that lets the base class use the `ClassA` and `InterfaceSeq & InterfaceClone` instances..